# Hey, I've got some problems with hiding a part of HTML DOM using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hide

I wanted to hide a part of my page from not showing up, but the HTML doesn't seem to work, please help me.

```js
document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <h1 align="center">Login</h1>
  <input type="text" id="Name2">
  <input type="password" id="Pass2">
  <button id="login">Sign Up</button>
  <button id="switch2">Not a user? Sign Up here.</button>
</div>
```

The same JS code works when I ran it through inspect tab of my browser, that time it worked.

It also doesn't show any particular error or anything.

And, I've added the script tag after the body tag, as I had learnt from a book to do so as getElementById only works if we do so.

Please help me (ಥ _ ಥ)

Comment: That code will either work or it will cause an error, if it is properly included in your page. How exactly are you including the JavaScript? What does the `<script>` tag look like, and where is it placed in the HTML?

Comment: seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/smd04ob5/, what is the problem really? can we have your entire code, especially the <script> maybe isn't linked correctly or something

Comment: Nah Mate, thanks for your concern, I found a way, thanks again.

Comment: And yeah, I had added the script tag correctly, I still don't know what the problem was but I found a way around it, thanks!